# ingress_expiry not within expected range error in candid ui. Motoko language, console prompted a breaking change on running dfx deploy

Tags: blockchain, motoko, dfinity

I was following a course tutorial to create a small decentralized bank application using dfinity's internet computer.
the main.mo file is as follows:

```
import Debug "mo:base/Debug";
import Float "mo:base/Float";
import Time "mo:base/Time";

actor DBank {
  stable var currentValue: Float = 300;
  stable var startTime = Time.now();
  Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));

  public func topUp(amount: Float){
    currentValue += amount;
    Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
  };

  public func withdraw(amount: Float){
    let tempValue: Float = currentValue - amount;
    if(tempValue >= 0){
        currentValue -= amount;
        Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
    } else{
      Debug.print("Withdrawal amount is more than Balance.")
    }
  };

  public query func checkBalance(): async Float{
    return currentValue;
  };

  public func compound() {
    let currentTime = Time.now();
    let timeElapsedNS = currentTime - startTime;
    let timeElapsedSec = timeElapsedNS / 1_000_000_000;
    currentValue := currentValue * (1.01 ** Float.fromInt(timeElapsedSec));
  };

}
```

```
The Candid Interface was working until I changed the the data type of currentValue from Nat to float. It showed a warning when i ran dfx deploy on the terminal:
user***@hp:~/ic-projects/dbank$ dfx deploy
Deploying all canisters.
All canisters have already been created.
Building canisters...
Building frontend...
Installing canisters...
WARNING!
Candid interface compatibility check failed for canister 'dbank'.
You are making a BREAKING change. Other canisters or frontend clients relying on your canister may stop working.

Method checkBalance: func () -> (float64) query is not a subtype of func () -> (nat) query
Do you want to proceed? yes/No
yes
```

I do not have the original warning, I tried to recreate it so float64 and nat might be interchanged.

On deployment the Candid UI shows this:
An error happened in Candid canister:
Error: Server returned an error:
Code: 400 (Bad Request)
Body: Specified ingress_expiry not within expected range:
Minimum allowed expiry: 2023-02-06 19:04:14.511184689 UTC
Maximum allowed expiry: 2023-02-06 19:09:44.511184689 UTC
Provided expiry:        2023-02-06 19:25:14.339 UTC
Local replica time:     2023-02-06 19:04:14.511189299 UTC

```
at _.query (http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.js:2:8821)
at async http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.js:2:100976
at async getRemoteDidJs (http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.js:2:266158)
at async Object.fetchActor (http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.js:2:265243)
at async http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.js:2:271946
```

I was thinking whether this could be a problem from Time module but couldn't find much about it, as the module documentation page has been removed.

Looked up the ingress_expiry problem and tried it's solutions:
the local machine's time is correct and in sync with the actual time.
Using wsl1 in vscode, it is the latest version i suppose as running wsl --update shows you have the latest version

The breaking change warning in the question description was orginally prompted for the checkBalance() function but I could not include anything worthwhile.

Comment: PS: The error got resolved. I deleted the canister and redeployed the project using 
`dfx delete canister --all` command and upon restarting it, the ui started working.

Comment: This is not working.

error: Found argument 'delete' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    dfx [OPTIONS] <SUBCOMMAND>

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu clock is not synchronized with system clock. Write this command in terminal of ubuntu sudo apt-get install ntp .This command will synchronize your ubuntu time with your system.  Make sure your system has correct time and date.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried this but getting below error.

Package ntp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ntp' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

In my case, below command worked.

```
sudo hwclock -s
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused because of unsyncronized time between Ubuntu and system time.
On running this `sudo hwclock -s` on the Ubuntu terminal and redeploying the app will eliminate the error.